# Why is the big bang considered a proof for Jewish tradition

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science

From the little I understand of the Big Bang (and that is VERY LITTLE), It states that the universe was in a very high density state and then expanded.

This is commonly used as a proof that the world had a beginning and thus torah tradition and science are not at odds. Dr. Gerald Schroeder wrote a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553354132) claiming this very position.

However, I was just thinking that the theory itself claims that there was a pre-existing kernel of mass that exploded and expanded. Thus, it was not a creation out of nothing.

Also doesn’t it presume that there was a "space" for it to expand into. Again, another previously extent object or matter.

Why is this a proof? Am I wrong I my understanding of the theory?

Comment: Where the singularity came from is a point of much discussion in physics. Some posit that it was in fact "nothing," but a flux due to collisions of n-branes that lead to gravitic density (singularity) without intrinsically anything being there. What Schroeder wrote was more about showing how Jewish tradition preemptively fits with modern sciences understanding of the BB, not just that "there was a beginning." When you're talking about it thousands of years before the concept is scientifically proposed, it speaks to something deeper.

Comment: What is an n brane a membrane? Like in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Also, the theory doesn't "claim" anything about the singularity itself. BB theory really only starts right AFTER the singularity explodes, since there is no reasonable method to explain anything before that point (such as HOW it could explode and where it came from).

Comment: Yes. an N-dimensional membrane. Brane theory is a fascinating extension of string theory, but we currently do not have methods to validate it experimentally.

Comment: Yeah I'm fake familiar with some parts of string theory, at least enough to sound interesting at a Kiddush.

Comment: What do you know about general relativity (particularly gravitational time dilation) and Hubble's Law (and metric space expansion)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35371/440

Comment: @Mefaresh Not a test. It's trying to help you understand the answer to your question. Although counter-intuitive, there may not have been any more space or time at the singularity which precipitated the big bang. (To be fair no one actually knows what happened at the singularity bc our equations break down. We can just describe in rough terms based on limits assuming no new factors.)

Comment: I think it's much more productive to think of this consonance as a fortunate instance of our understandings of God's two major revelations to us - the natural world and the Torah - converging, rather than as a proof.

Comment: Dr. Schroeder has an interesting equation matching the six days' expansion with the cosmological date of the universe. The Medrash at the end of Bereishis also says that until Adam's sin the stars moved much faster.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky to say that n-branes hit each other to cause it, doesn't that presume pre existing matter?

Comment: Branes are not matter, they are n-dimensional layers of spacetime. The crossing/collision of branes may create "bubbles" of space-time in which universes form. Technically, this assumes prexistence of "higher dimensional stuff," but not necessarily matter per se. The energy at the point of collision would lead to warping, a singularity, and the ensuing Big Bang. That's the theory, anyhow. It's pretty trippy to think about...

Comment: "Also that there was a 'space' for it to expand into. Again, another previously extent object or matter." That is incorrect. The scientific consensus is that the universe is constantly expanding, but outside the universe is nothing. It's not space as space exists only within the universe.

Comment: there was no space to expand into. the big bang was the creation of space and its subsequent expansion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think their main point is not that the theory in all its details is identical to the Jewish tradition. For thousands of years, conventional western wisdom was based on the Aristotelian assumption of *kadmuth ha'olam* - that the universe always was as it is. The modern discoveries of physics which talk about a finite point in time before which human speculation is pointless is much more in line with Jewish tradition (see, however, Moreh Nevukhim, who points out that technically even *kadmuth ha'olam* would not necessarily be a heretical idea).

Comment: Correct, we can't ASK Mah Lifnim, but that doesn't preclude there BEING something in that domain...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky maybe but it is much more compatible with the torah's account than aristotel's view

Comment: where does the moreh nevuchim say kadmut haolam is not heretical? rambam says in many places that only God can be eternally existing

Comment: @ray I don't think we're in disagreement on this... :D

Comment: Rambam doesn't say that; this is a misconception based on a misreading of Moreh Nevuchim 2:25 @ray

Comment: @wfb not he says it clearly in yesodei hatorah 1

Answer (score 1):

The point about the "Big Bang" is that given a point of creation, there must have been a creator. Thus, if the Big Bang was not the point of creation of the universe, then whatever came before had to have been created. Or perhaps whatever came "before" that or ...

Once scientists dropped the "eternal universe" theory for some starting point, They eventually get back to some point of creation (which is what we said from the beginning).

Our dating everything from the Creation of Adam means that we really do not understand exactly how Hashem created the Universe and what it entailed. We just know that he did **something** to cause the Universe to exist. That is why the Torah only gives a rough sketch and it is forbidden to try to teach the "Maaseh Beraishis" to two people as it involves subjects that are too deep to be explained to more than a single student.

For example I also mention the issue at [What caused God?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56662/what-caused-god/56667#56667)